# NSPredicate Prioritizing Returned Values

Tags: swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

I have a CKRecord of recipes. The user types in two ingredients (a `carbohydrate` and a `vegetable`) and a list of recipes is returned. I got that working. I'm also using collaborative filtering elsewhere in my code to say "hey, new user, other people liked these recipes!"

How do I raise those recipe_ids to the top of my query list?

The below code returns not results because I'm telling to give me results that both have the desired `likedIds` and also recipes which are not in `likedIds`. But how do I go about placing the `likedIds` at the top of the list?

```
    let searchTextA: [String] = [carbohydrate," "+carbohydrate,carbohydrate+"s",carbohydrate+"es"]
    let subPred1 = NSPredicate (format: "ANY ingredients IN %@",argumentArray: [searchTextA])
    let searchTextB: [String] = [vegetable," "+vegetable,vegetable+"s",vegetable+"es"]
    let subPred2 = NSPredicate (format: "ANY ingredients IN %@",argumentArray: [searchTextB])
    let likedIds: [Int] = [13733,32441]
    let subPred3 = NSPredicate (format: "recipe_id IN %@",argumentArray: [likedIds])
    let subPred4 = NSPredicate (format: "NOT (recipe_id IN %@)", likedIds)
    let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [subPred1, subPred2, subPred3, subPred4])
```

Comment: `NSPredicate` can't sort, use `sortDescriptors` or append the results of query `NOT (recipe_id IN %@)` to the results of query `recipe_id IN %@`.

Comment: @Willeke that later option is precisely what I want! Can you please help me with what that code would look like to "append the results of query `NOT (recipe_id IN %@)` to the results of query `recipe_id IN %@` "?

Comment: Okay, @Willeke with some work I was able to append each query onto `[CKQuery]` which is a list of CKQuery. Yet, I'm stuck now, how do I call `publicDB.perform(queries, inZoneWith: CKRecordZone.default().zoneID)` with my `[CKQuery]`? I get the error: `Cannot convert value of type '[CKQuery]' to expected argument type 'CKQuery'` I tried putting each `CKQuery` into a forloop but it's very random at that point which of the CKQuery's actually populates. Can you please help me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cloudkit, maybe someone else can help.